# Index an object multiple levels deep with one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
object.day.time
```

where I need to access the time property.

Due to the nature of the function, I only have access to the base object. I.E.

```
function access(property){
    let item = object[property]
    // Do a lot of stuff with item
}
```

I don't want to rewrite the function because the main use case is accessing objects one level deep. I.E. the day property. Is there any way I can make this work?

The only thing I could think of was:

```
property = [['day']['time']]
```

but that didn't work.

EDIT: I originally had object as a param to access which was wrong. I that case I could just pass object.day as a value

Comment: If you only want to use your `access` function, you'll have to rewrite it, at least a bit. Right now, you cannot expect to access the second level, since, as you stated, it is only designed for the main use case, which is one level object.

Comment: Can't you just call `access` this way: `access(object.day, 'time')` ?

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I didn't mean to put object as a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do sometime like this to go to this `time` property:

```js
var object = {
   day: {
      time: (new Date()).getTime()
   }
};

var properties = ["day","time"];

function access(object,properties){
   for(var index=0; index < properties.length; index++){
      // go to deeper into object until your reached time 
      object = object[properties[index]];
   }
   // here we have reached time and can do something with it or just returning it
   return object;
}

console.log(access(object,properties));
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this function pass object.day instead of just the base object which means the object in the function will already be object.day so if you do object.time, you should get the value.